# Getting Program to run again in C

Tags: c

I have this program that ask the user to guess a number that is randomly generated between 1 and 20. At the end I ask the user if they want to go again by entering a 1 for yes and a 0 for no. I know that a while loop should be used but when I select 1 to run again it will only run the first line of code again. Also I must account for the user not entering a 1 or 0 and it should ask the user to enter a valid input until it is a valid 1 or 0. I believe I have this correct but am not sure. Any help would be great!

```
     int main(void)
{
    int trys=0;
    int guess;
    int points=0;
    int number;
    int again=1;
    int count=1;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-Guess the Number*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-\n");

    while(again!=0)
    {
        number=rand()%20 + 1;
        printf("Guess a number between 1 and 20:  ");
        scanf("%i", &guess);
        trys=trys+1;

        while (trys<3)
        {
            if (guess<1 || guess>20)
            {
                printf("Invalid input! Enter a value between 1 and 20:  ");
                scanf("%i", &guess);
            }
            else if(guess>number)
            {   
                /*If the area is incorrect, the user will get this message*/
                printf("Guess Lower:  "); 
                scanf("%i", &guess);
                trys=trys+1;

                if (trys==3 && guess==number)
                {
                    printf("\nGood Job! You earned a point.\n");
                    points=points+1;
                    printf("You have %i points!\n",points);
                }
            }
            else if (guess<number)
            {
                printf("Guess Higher:  ");
                scanf("%i", &guess);
                trys=trys+1;

                if (trys==3 && guess==number)
                {
                    printf("\nGood Job! You earned a point.\n");
                    points=points+1;
                    printf("You have %i points!\n",points);
                }
            }
            else if(guess==number)
            {   
                trys=3;
                printf("\nGood job! You earned a point.\n");
                points=points+1;
                printf("You have %i points!\n",points);
            }

        }
        if (trys==3 && guess!= number)
        {
            printf("\nSorry, the number was %i. Try again.\n",number);  
            printf("You have %i total points\n\n",points);
        }


        printf("Would you like to play again? (1 for yes, 0 for no)  ");
        scanf("%i", &again);

        while(count==3)
        {
            if(again>1 || again<0)
            {
                printf("Invalid input! Enter a 1 for yes or a 0 for no:  ");
                scanf("%i", &again);
            }
            else if(again==1 || again==0)
            {
                count=3;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the posted code:

```
1) is missing the three needed header files stdio.h stdlib.h and time.h
2) fails to reset the `tries` counter at the top of the outermost loop
```

It would be a very good idea to check for errors, so each call to scanf() should be followed by a check of the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

I.E. what if the user enters only a newline or enters an alpha value or enters a control character, like ^d?

in the 'while' loop that is checking for a valid 'replay' entry (0...1).  What if the user keeps entering a newline or 6 or 'n' or ...

for good program flow, for the outerloop, suggest: `do .... while( 1 == again );

BTW: to avoid long frustrating searches through code for where a comparison `==` was accidentally written as `=`, place the literal on the left side.  Then the compiler would catch the problem.

regarding this loop:

while(count==3)
        {
            if(again>1 || again<0)
            {
                printf("Invalid input! Enter a 1 for yes or a 0 for no:  ");
                scanf("%i", &again);
            }
            else if(again==1 || again==0)
            {
                count=3;
            }
        }

comparing count to 3 is a bad idea as the loop does not modify the value of count and the count will always be 1, so this loop will never be entered